# How to use Elasticsearch on ActiveRecord::Relation collection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, elasticsearch, activerecord

I have an issue while using Elasticsearch method `search` on ActiveRecord::Relation collection. 
For example: I got collection

```
@completed_courses = Course.where(completed: true)
```

If I call elasticsearch method `search` on ActiveRecord::Relation collection `@completed_courses`

```
@completed_courses.search(params[:query])
```

it will find data among **all** `Coures` model records Not among `@completed_courses` collection, but I need make search only among `@completed_courses` records. 
How to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to use Elasticsearch to search on a specific subset of your model. `@completed_courses` only exists within memory in the runtime of your ruby controller (presumably) and Elasticsearch has no view of that.

Your best bet is to index the `completed` field on your model so you can include it as part of your Elasticsearch `search()` queries and this should get you what you are looking for!

Comment: No problem, glad it was helpful